# Realm Db getting parent child objects repeating infinity times

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list, realm-migration

I have a realm db schema like shown below.

```
const ParentSchema = {
  name: 'parent',
  properties: {
    id: 'string',
    father_name: 'string',
    children: { type: 'linkingObjects', objectType: 'child', property: 'parent' },
  },
  primaryKey: 'id',
};


const ChildSchema = {
  name: 'child',
  properties: {
    id: 'string',
    first_name: 'string',
    parent: { type: 'parent' },
  },
  primaryKey: 'id',
};
```

First i want to know if its ok for parent child relationship? i need parents with their childs and child with parent.

The issue is when i get child i get list of children with his parent and parent has again a list of children and childeren has parent and again parent has children. and this goes so on..

Same this applies when i get list of parents.

```
let data = realm.objects('parent');
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to include your actual Realm Swift Object models from XCode? What's shown is a bit incomplete with objectType of 'student' because there is no `student` shown. It also seems your relationships are not set up correctly; in general the `Parent` object would have a `List` of `Children` objects and each child would have a `LinkingObjects` property back to the parent. That allows the graph to be transversed in both directions. Update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: student was there by mistake, i have updated it.

Comment: Again, please include your actual Realm Objects in the question so we can see how they are set up. Then also include an actual query you want to run, what's shown doesn't give us an indication of what you want returned, other than all of the parent objects. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)